# Foundation top bar dropdown not respecting ajax links

Tags: javascript, ajax, zurb-foundation

Been working on a web application built with Zurb Foundation 4 and I'm running into a little trouble that no one else seems to be having. I'm using the standard top bar implementation that works flawlessly, like so...

```
<ul class="left">
  <li><a href="/pageone" class="ajax_go">Page One</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">More...</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a class="ajax_go" href="/pagetwo">Page Two</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've created a ajax_go handler to load my content via ajax using this function...

```
$(document).on("click", ".ajax_go", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var page_name = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: page_name + '?ajax=1',
        success: function(result){
            $('#content').html(result);
            $(document).foundation('section','reflow');
        }
    });
    if(page_name!=window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path:page_name},'',page_name);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Now I don't have any issue with top-level links, but my function fails on dropdown items. Clicking on "Page One" works as intended but clicking on "Page Two" falls back to the default action of loading a new page. I couldn't figure out what to remove from foundation.topbar.js but I assume some javascript is affecting dropdown links.

It also fails every time if I load the page in a mobile width.